When I try to add a new user by "useradd -c" inside while loop in Ubuntu24.04 doens't work, but at the other Ubuntu version the same script works
I'm a new student at the Linux Command and Shell Script and I'm reading the book called Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible, Third Edition. In this book, on the 361 page, there is a script like the following
#!/bin/bash
# process new user accounts
input="users.csv"
while IFS=',' read -r userid name
do
 echo "adding $userid"
 useradd -c "$name" -m $userid
done < "$input"

Within the users.cvs file it has
rich,Richard Blum
christine,Christine Bresnahan
barbara,Barbara Blum
tim,Timothy Bresnahan

I'm using WSL to study Shell Script and I installed the Linux Ubuntu 24.04. But, when I ran the script above it happened the following problem
adding: rich
useradd: failure while writing changes to /etc/passwd

adding: christine
useradd: failure while writing changes to /etc/passwd

adding: barbara
useradd: failure while writing changes to /etc/passwd

adding: tim
useradd: failure while writing changes to /etc/passwd

But when I ran exactly the same script with the same users.csv file at the other lower Linux Ubuntu version the script works...
I'm trying to understand what is the problem... Someone could help me?
I tried to run the following script
#!/bin/bash
usertest="christine"
nametest="Christine Blum"

echo "adding: $usertest"
echo "name: $nametest"

useradd -c "$nametest" -m $usertest

At the Ubuntu24.04 works, but when you put he "useradd" inside the while loop with reading users.csv file doens't work...

Is the WSL version of the users.csv file in DOS/Windows text format? If so, that'll cause weird problems (possibly including this one). See "Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?" and "Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"

Change in your  script the echo "adding $userid" to echo user $name as $userid and let as know what you see.

I suppose you ran the script as sudo, right?
